# Test function to distinguish between irrational and rational numbers

Tags: real-analysis

I just read on this forum that if a continuous function $f(x)$ has the property that $f(x) =0$ for all rational values of $x$ in its domain, then it follows that $f(x)$ is necassarily also zero for irrational values of $x$ in its domain.

This made be wonder: why it is not feasible to construct a sieve function, that is especially designed to distinguish between rational numbers and irrational number?

I came up with the following function $f(x)$. The domain is the set of real numbers from $(0, 1)$.

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{S}$$

$$S = \sum_{j=2}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{j-1} \frac{1}{c + j^2*abs(jx-k)}$$

where $c$ is an infinitesimally small parameter. I put it there to prevent divergences in numerical simulations, when a rational number satisfies $x = k/j$. Note that the double sum over $j$ and $k$ generates this sequence of rational numbers ${1/2, 1/3, 2/3, 1/4, 2/4, 3/4, 1/5, 2/5, 3/5, 4/5....}$.

Now if we take an irrational input value, for example $x = \pi -3$, the function value becomes roughly $0.2$. However if we take a nearby rational number, $x = 355/113 - 3$, the values of $f$ drops to the infinitessimally small value $c$ and never rises again (in fact it decreases even further).

Question: Is the function $f(x)$ a counter-example to what was stated in the first paragraph? Or are there problems with such a function?

Comment: I hope this is the format you wanted. Otherwise, sorry, and of course, feel free to edit.

Comment: What precisely is the question here?

Comment: @Meelo: I think it is whether this function serves or can serve to distinguish Rationals from Irrationals. But I am not sure of how M.wind intended it to be so.

Comment: what do you mean the double sum over $j$ and $k$ generates this sequence of rational numbers? Since the double sum only depends on $x$, how are they related?

Comment: The pairs (j,k) form the rational numbers k/j. The absolute value of the difference between x and k/j is evaluated and summed.

Comment: $f$ is definitely $0$ on some irrationals to start with - e.g. a [Liouville number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number). I wouldn't be surprised at all if it equals $0$ everywhere (though I don't think it does). If it's not $0$ somewhere, then it is definitely discontinuous though. There's no reason to believe it ought to be continuous anyways.

Comment: Also, if nobody else is going to point this out, then I will. Don't throw around the word "infinitesimal" in a pure math setting unless you have some sort of nonstandard analysis under your belt. Otherwise, you more than likely don't have the foundation needed to speak rigorously on it. And when a theorem says, "An object A with some property P does not exist," then it might be a good exercise to try to make it and see why it doesn't work, but if the theorem is accurate (which Julian showed quite simply below), then it is quite impossible to find a counter-example.

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious that it cannot be a counterexample, since what you read is true.

**Theorem.** If $f\colon(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in(0,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}$, then $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in(0,1)$.

**Proof.** $(0,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $(0,1)$. If $x\in(0,1)$ there is a sequence of rational numbers $\{x_n\}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=0$.

Comment: Undoubtedly this theorem is sound. On the other hand, we are at liberty to: (a) define S, a set of points on the x-axis in the interval [0,1]. (b) choose a point P = (x, y) in the xy-plane. (c) define f(x, y) as the reciprocal of the weighted average reciprocal distance between P and the points in S. This function is continuous and yields a non-zero output for P outside of the (0, 1) interval on the x-axis. (d) examine what happens to f in the limit of P approaching a point on the x-axis in the (0,1) interval.

Comment: The question was: is this function a counterexample? The answer is no.

Comment: My follow-up question is: what goes wrong if we follow the approach mentioned in my previous comment?